# Plotting multiple ellipses on same figure with data from text file

Tags: python, file, plot, ellipse

I am new to python, so I am sorry if this is too trivial.

This is an example of the first two lines of the text file.

> ra dec major_axis minor_axis position_angle
>
> 149.20562 2.29594 0.00418 0.00310 83.40

Each line of the file has 5 parameters which is needed to plot one ellipse. The first two columns are for the center. The next 3 columns are major axis, minor axis and position angle respectively. This file is part of a huge catalog which has many lines. I want to plot all those ellipses in one figure.

Here is what I tried.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import astropy.io.ascii as asciitable
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse


path=/users/vishnu/Desktop/
fw=open(path + 'data_plot.txt', 'r')
table = asciitable.read(path+ "data_plot.txt")
ra_degrees=[table['ra']]
dec_degrees=[table['dec']]
major_axis_deg=[table['major_axis']]
minor_axis_deg=[table['minor_axis']]
position_angle_deg=[table['position_angle']]



for ra, dec, w, h, angle in zip(ra_degrees,
dec_degrees,major_axis_deg, minor_axis_deg, position_angle_deg):
    ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(ra, dec), width=w, height=h, angle=angle)
    ax.add_patch(ellipse)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
fw.close()
```

This is the error log.

```
  runfile('/users/vishnu/.spyder2-py3/radio_sources.py', wdir='/users/vishnu/.spyder2-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-299-a0011c0326f5>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/users/vishnu/.spyder2-py3/radio_sources.py', wdir='/users/vishnu/.spyder2-py3')

  File "/users/vishnu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/users/vishnu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/users/vishnu/.spyder2-py3/radio_sources.py", line 63, in <module>
    ax.add_patch(ellipse)

  File "/users/vishnu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1783, in add_patch
    self._update_patch_limits(p)

  File "/users/vishnu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1803, in _update_patch_limits
    xys = patch.get_patch_transform().transform(vertices)

  File "/users/vishnu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py", line 1409, in get_patch_transform
    self._recompute_transform()

  File "/users/vishnu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py", line 1398, in _recompute_transform
    .scale(width * 0.5, height * 0.5) \

  File "/users/vishnu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 1965, in scale
    np.float_)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Please also let me know if there is a smarter way to do this without the need to create arrays.

Comment: Post the full traceback. In particular what line of your code caused the error?

Comment: I have updated the post now.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to use a PatchCollection, see [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/patch_collection.html). Try something like this

```
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ellipses = []
plt.xlim([0,100])
plt.ylim([0,100])
for ra, dec, w ... zip(...):
    ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(ra, dec), width=w, height=h, angle=angle)
    ellipses.append(ellipse)
p = PatchCollection(ellipses)
ax.add_collection(p)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This shows an empty figure with no plots. The scale doesn't change. How do I auto adjust the scale of x and y axis based on the data?

Comment: you can adjust x and y limits with plt.xlim and plt.ylim. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the problem is that you have one too many levels of nesting on ra_degrees, etc.

That is, if you print table['ra'] you will probably find that it is already an array.  When you enclose it in square brackets, [table['ra']] will then be a list of length one. The zip function takes one item from each sequence at a time, so in your for loop, ra will be assigned table['ra'] the first and only time through the loop.

Another issue is that you are opening the file twice.  You are passing the filename to asciitable.read, and are never actually using fw.

The code below might work better.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import astropy.io.ascii as asciitable

path=/users/vishnu/Desktop/
table = asciitable.read(path + "data_plot.txt")

ra_degrees = table['ra']
dec_degrees = table['dec']
major_axis_deg = table['major_axis']
minor_axis_deg = table['minor_axis']
position_angle_deg = table['position_angle']

for ra, dec, w, h, angle in zip(ra_degrees, dec_degrees,
        major_axis_deg, minor_axis_deg, position_angle_deg):
    ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(ra, dec), width=w, height=h, angle=angle)
    ax.add_patch(ellipse)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

If asciitable works with an open file rather than a file name, then use the following instead:

```
with open(path + "data_plot.txt") as fw:
    table = asciitable.read(fw)
```

This makes sure that the file is closed even if there are errors in asciitable.read that cause it to raise an exception.  Given the error above, though, it looks like you have already read the data.